# How to control Z-Order of UITableView in a SpriteKit scene?

Tags: ios, uikit, xamarin, sprite-kit, z-order

I have an iOS SpriteKit SKScene that contains a UIKit UITableView as part of the scene via View.AddSubview. Generally this works fine. I then create an SKNode that temporarily sits on top of the scene (to zoom in on a particular image) and I want it to be at the top of the z-order, so I set ZPosition of the new node to 999 arbitrarily. When the node is added, it appears on top of all the other SpriteKit nodes, but the UITableView is still at the top of the z-order and still accepts input even though there is a sprite node on top of it (supposedly).

Is there a way to set the z-order of a UIKit view when it is hosted on a SpriteKit scene so I can push it backwards?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Any UIView added to the SKView sits on top of everything rendered by the SKView. Nodes rendered by SKView and the SKScene itself aren't views, they are elements inside the SKView much like table cells are part of UITableView, but you can only change the draw order of the UITableView and the SKView. You can't take individual elements (nodes or cells) and draw them outside their container views.

The same issue exists in other 2d renderers by the way, be it cocos2d or plain OpenGL.